# Changing texture offset in unity by script

Tags: unity, textures, vector, scripting, parallax-scrolling

I am trying to change texture offset in a material by a script to create a parallax effect, but it doesn't move a bit no matter what I am trying. Any tips for this case? Or am I missing something?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image. Text is better for searching, accessibility, and copy-pasting for trying to replicate problems or include snippets in answers.

Comment: Sorry. I will. Is there any convenient way to post code? When I just Ctrl + V it make quite a mess.

Comment: Select your code and press the button that looks like {} to format it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Should have used SetTextureOffset method. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetTextureOffset.html